# I am trying to concatinate multiple csv files (13 files) into one (column wise) and the results i am getting is not coming column wise

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, concatenation

```
     import pandas as pd
     dfs_AIC = []
     for filenum in range(1,13):
         dfs_AIC.append( pd.read_csv('AIC_{}.csv'.format(filenum)) )
     aaa_pvalue=(pd.concat(dfs_AIC).to_csv("AIC_Concatinate_1-13.csv"))
```

I am trying to concatinate multiple csv files (13 files) into one (column wise) and the results i am getting is not coming column wise, instead i am getting concatenated values diagonally in resulting csv. what could be the error in code?

Comment: Can you add an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 import pandas as pd
 dfs_AIC = pd.DataFrame()
 for filenum in range(1,13):
     dfs_AIC.append(pd.read_csv('AIC_{}.csv'.format(filenum)) )
```

This will create one big dataframe with all the rows.